# conditional shift operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df as

```
print (df)
   ACTUAL  TARGET ACTUAL_DATE  NO  YEAR
0    6385  108725    9/5/2018  36  2018
1    6385  108725    9/4/2018  36  2018
2    3251  108725    9/3/2018  36  2018
3    1793  120941    9/2/2018  35  2018
4    1037  120941    9/1/2018  35  2018
5  121127  120941   8/31/2018  35  2018
6  116232  120941   8/30/2018  35  2018
7  111820  120941   8/29/2018  35  2018
8  106402  120941   8/28/2018  35  2018
```

and i am looking to for an output like

[image]

Notice new column ACTUAL_SALES is just the difference of ACTUAL - ACTUAL(Previous)

I tried to use,

```
if a['ACTUAL_DATE'].dt.month == a['ACTUAL_DATE'].shift(1).dt.month:
    a['ACTUAL_SALES'] = a['ACTUAL'] - a['ACTUAL'].shift(-1)   
else:
    a['ACTUAL_SALES'] = a['ACTUAL']
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I also tried,

```
 if a['ACTUAL_DATE'].dt.month == a['ACTUAL_DATE'].shift(1).dt.month:
    a['ACTUAL_SALES'] = a['ACTUAL'].diff(-1)  
 else:
    a['ACTUAL_SALES'] = a['ACTUAL']
```

**I have found a way to get the desired output., but i am looking to understand why i keep getting above error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by month period what working if multiple years with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and replace last values of each month by original column by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), last convert column to integer:

```
df['ACTUAL_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ACTUAL_DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df['ACTUAL_SALES'] = (df.groupby(df['ACTUAL_DATE'].dt.to_period('m'))['ACTUAL']
                        .diff(-1)
                        .fillna(df['ACTUAL'])
                        .astype(int))
print (df)
   ACTUAL  TARGET ACTUAL_DATE  NO  YEAR  ACTUAL_SALES
0    6385  108725  2018-09-05  36  2018             0
1    6385  108725  2018-09-04  36  2018          3134
2    3251  108725  2018-09-03  36  2018          1458
3    1793  120941  2018-09-02  35  2018           756
4    1037  120941  2018-09-01  35  2018          1037
5  121127  120941  2018-08-31  35  2018          4895
6  116232  120941  2018-08-30  35  2018          4412
7  111820  120941  2018-08-29  35  2018          5418
8  106402  120941  2018-08-28  35  2018        106402
```